# git "rebase" only a few commits from external repo?

Tags: git

Say I have a repo X:

```
<a very long history>-A-B-C-D-E
```

And another guy has a repo Y:

```
<another very long history>-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-...
```

I want to "rebase" `c-d` to my repo and get:

```
<a very long history>-A-B-C-D-E-c'-d'
```

where c' is E plus diff (b..c) with exactly same commit message, author date, author name, and author email with c, and d' is c' plus diff (c..d) and same info with d.

I want to achieve this WITHOUT fetching the complete `<another very long history>-a-b-c-d-e` branch from repo Y first. Is there any illustration?

Comment: You can ask the other guy to send you patches for commits `c` and `d` (using `git format-patch b..d`)

Comment: @phoet: cherry picking only works after fetching the history.

Comment: @knittl yeah that's true... otherwise git would not know about the commit hash :)

Comment: Op asked specifically for a solution that does not involve fetching (a long history) from the other repository first

Answer (score 2):

Sure: do your fetch `--depth=3` so you get only commits `b`, `c`, and `d`.

You don't need to even add a remote, let alone clone, for something this simple. Just do

```
git fetch --depth=3 u://r/l branch
git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD~2..FETCH_HEAD
```

[hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560182/git-rebase-only-a-few-commits-from-external-repo/19560809?noredirect=1#comment29029855_19560809) that doing a depth-limited fetch marks your repository as shallow, which will disable fetching or cloning from it.  Since you're not actually publishing the shallow histories (the only reference to them is the `FETCH_HEAD` temporary) you can just remove the file with

```
rm .git/shallow    # safe when no shallow histories are published
```

Comment: According to the docs, `git fetch --depth` is for repos that were created with `git clone --depth`. But it would make sense if it works here too, and in that case, sure, this is much simpler than my answer.

Comment: @hvd huh.  It will certainly do what the docs say it'll do, but it'll also do the above.  I figured clone had to be passing `--depth` on to `fetch` and just never bothered to read its docs.

Comment: I've done some testing now, my answer wouldn't work. Yours would. It would, however, mark the local repository as shallow. You need to remove the `.git/shallow` file when you're done. The effect of that file is that it is not an error when a commit's parent does not exist, but some operations are disallowed. When you're done, there should not be any reachable commits whose parents don't exist, so it should be safe to remove that file.

Comment: Is it possible that if the other guy has `<another very long history>-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m` and I "fetch" only `b-c-d` to do a cherry-pick?

Comment: It'll take cooperation from the other repo's administrator -- you can fetch anything with a ref, so get them to add a ref.  Easiest is to do a lightweight tag, say `git tag for-danny $d` or something, and when you're done with it you can `git push $them +:refs/tags/for-danny` (or have them delete it if their repo's configured to reject all remote ref deletion) to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

Without fetching the history of the other repository, I cannot see another solution than asking the other guy to send the patches via mail.

Note, that if she/he sends them by mail, she/he is still the *author* of the commits, but you are the commiter!

Comment: This helps since the case may be to graft revision 1000 and 4000 from a repo branch with 7000 revisions for example.

Nevertheless, I'd like to know if the hashes of the revisions are known (eg. seen on the GitHub), is there a way to get their patches from the remote repo without bothering the author?

Answer (score 0):

fetching is required ( `git fetch --all` ), but you can rebase on a remote ref.

Let's say you want rebase on the branch "master" of the Y repo (Y is the name you set with `git remote add Y http://url/to/Y/repo` ) :

```
git rebase Y/master
```